# Trying to install easyGgplot2 in R

Tags: r

I am trying to install the easyGgplot2 packages in R 3.5.2

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("kassambara/easyGgplot2")
```

The last command leads to the following error:

```
package ‘assertthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘colorspace’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘crayon’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error: (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘digest’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
```

Apparently, there is an error with the digest package.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please following below code and you problem will be solved. Good luck!

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("kassambara/easyGgplot2")
```

Comment: Your answer can be improved by explaining _why_ the supplied code works, and contrast it to why OPs code does not. Also, why are you loading `devtools`, when you are calling the function directly with `::`?

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the below code solved this problem for me.

```
    install.packages("remotes")
    remotes::install_github("kassambara/easyGgplot2")
```